# How to modify text inside iframe from mailchimp

Tags: jquery, iframe

I've got an `iframe` from MailChimp and I'm trying to modify it with jQuery. I'm trying to put a link inside the text. However I have no luck modifying it, especially because the `iframe` does not have an `id`.

I have tried to change it with the following jQuery, but it's not working. I will be grateful for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#PopupSignupForm_0 iframe').load(function() {
    $('#PopupSignupForm_0 iframe').contents().find('body .content__gdprFields .field-wrapper .checkbox span').html('Change it');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#PopupSignupForm_0 iframe').on('load', function() {
    $(this).contents().find("body").html('<p>hi</p>');
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="PopupSignupForm_0" widgetid="PopupSignupForm_0">
  <div class="mc-banner" data-dojo-attach-point="bannerContainer" style="display: block;">
    <div class="mc-layout__bannerContent">
      <iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 116px;" data-dojo-attach-point="iframeBannerContainer"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-modal" data-dojo-attach-point="modalContainer" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="mc-closeModal" data-action="close-mc-modal" data-dojo-attach-point="modalClose"></div>
    <div class="mc-layout__modalContent" style="max-height: 1225px;">
      <iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 100%; height: 1225px;" data-dojo-attach-point="iframeModalContainer">
        Rest of iframe...
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We can't really help you without knowing what the content of the iframe looks like. Are you loading them locally, or are they pointing to third party domains? What relevance does MailChimp have in any of this?

Comment: If the content of the iframe is coming from a different domain to the parent window then you cannot access it via JS for various security reasons

Comment: Thx for information!